# How to invert this matrix?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Is there a smarter method for finding the determinant and inverse of the following matrix, without using the brute force procedure? (When I say brute force, it is to write the matrix with each term explicitly.)
$$ M= \left(a\mathbb{1}_{4\times4} + b\gamma^0 + c_i\gamma^i\gamma_5 \right) $$

whre $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma_i$ are some representation of the Dirac matrices, $c_i$ are just components of a vector and $a$ and $b$ are real constants.

Comment: The inverse seems doable, the determinant is trickier. Any reason you don't like the brute force approach? it shouldn't take more than 10 seconds...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I'd like to learn a more elegant form to do it

Comment: Did you notice all three terms commute with each other, so behave like "numbers"?